# What is the most idiomatic way to load and save values from an MFC CPropertySheet?

Tags: properties, mfc

I have a class derived from `CPropertySheet` and I am having trouble finding the "correct" way to load values on startup and save values when the user presses OK.  I'm surprised that I can't find any useful example on the web but there it is.

Ultimately, I need to read values from an external data source and write them back but for now, I have a `void LoadValues(void)` method on my property sheet that just uses some literals to initialize the controls on the property pages.  This works when I call `LoadValues()` from `OnInitDialog()`.  But if I do:

```
CMyPropertySheet* pSheet = new CMyPropertySheet("My Title");

pSheet->LoadValues();

if (pSheet->DoModal() == IDOK) {
   pSheet->SaveValues();
   delete pSheet;
}
```

(as [Microsoft suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17tta0t9.aspx)) the values are not there when the property page is displayed; the controls are empty or contain default values.  All the MFC control value setting routines seem to return `void` so there's nothing to test for success.  I did read back a value in `LoadValues()` after I set it and I get the correct value.

Also, `SaveValues()` sees gibberish.  Perhaps the property sheet is torn down before I get out of `DoModal()` to the values aren't there any more?

I've been told that values should get loaded in `OnInitDialog()` and I guess I can get my external data source to the object in the constructor but that leaves me having no idea where to *save* values.  There doesn't seem to be a `CPropertySheet::OnOK()` method.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code for LoadValues?  _The values do not show up_ - where?

Comment: I have not stepped through.  What would be the point?  None of the control value-setting methods return a success or failure.

Comment: For starters, how will you know what the problem is if you don't step through the code?  You imply that you load the values and that they don't "show up" somewhere.  Stepping through the code should help determine why that is.

Comment: Your controls are filled when the property page dialogs OnInitDialog is called. When you use the standard DDX methods. Did you call the parent class PropertyPage::OnInitDialog  otherwise UpdateData is not called upon loading the sheet...

Comment: My derived class calls `CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog` in its `OnInitDialog`.  And my other derived class calls `CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog` in its `OnInitDialog`.  If I put my `LoadValues()` call in `MyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()`) all the pages of my sheet get populated with the intended values.  But where does/can `OnInitDialog()` get those values?  Right now, they are hard coded but later I need to pass a data source (struct, or something) that has those values.  I guess I could pass it to the constructor and stick it way for later use but that seems awkward and indirect.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are working with a property sheet the same issues apply to all modal dialogs. Before you call DoModal the controls do not exist. So if your LoadValues call is attempting to access the controls it will not work. (This would normally produce an assertion in a debug build.) What you need is a two-step operation: (1) LoadValues can access data members of the sheet, so pass the values to the sheet's data members that you create for that purpose. (2) In OnInitDialog of the sheet you can initialize the controls from the data members.

SaveValues needs a similar two-step because the controls no longer exist after DoModal returns. (1) In the sheet's OnOK or equivalent move the data from controls to data members. (2) After DoModal returns you can access the data members to do the SaveValues.

Comment: Though, of course, `CPropertySheet` is derived from `CWnd` which has no `OnOK`.  I added a `OnBnClickedOK` method to my property sheet and call `SaveValues` from there.  That works but it seems odd that there is it no "save now" virtual method on `CPropertySheet`.

Comment: To paraphrase (or sum up), the idiomatic way is 1) create the property sheet, 2) do something to attach values to the sheet (e.g., set data members), 3) In `OnInitDialog` copy from data members to control members,  4) Add an `OnOK` that copies from control members to data members, 5) After `DoModal`, copy get values out of the sheet (e.g., read data members).